# How to check if a value is greater than within an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following SQL statement:

```
$query  = "SELECT item, COUNT(*) as number FROM shop GROUP BY item";
```

This will give me the following result:

```
item    number
item1       23
item2       15
item3        4
```

I want to use this to make menu items, so normally the menu would look:

```
item1
item2
item3
```

But I want to do a check if an item has less than 10 records, that I don't want to display this item.

So in this example, the menu would be like:

```
item1
item2
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

I would like to do this in PHP because I need all the items in the query but will only want to show them which are greater then 10 and need the other items later on.

Comment: `where number > 10`..?

Comment: or number >= 10 ?

Comment: Number's is an alias for count so he actually has to do HAVING NUMBER>=10

Comment: Yes, you can't do `WHERE COUNT(*) > 10` ...

Comment: But how to do this with the array in PHP?

Comment: you want to do this in mysql or php @Arie ?

Comment: I would like to do this in PHP because I need all the items in the query but will only want to show them which are greater then 10

Comment: @pabrantes I always get my SQL wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this in PHP then you can do like this

```
function filterArray($value){
    return ($value.number > 10);
}

$filteredArray = array_filter($yourDBArray, 'filterArray');

foreach($filteredArray as $k => $v){
    //your desired array
}
```

In terms of speed Mysql option is good as suggested above.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your query from

`SELECT item, COUNT(*) as number FROM shop GROUP BY item`

to

`SELECT item, COUNT(*) as number FROM shop GROUP BY item HAVING number>=10`

Answer (score 1):

As you really need to perform this in PHP you could use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) which, using a [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php), will remove items which `number` is less than 10:

```
$more_than_ten = array_filter($items, function ($i) { return $i['number'] >= 10; });
```

---

Doing it with SQL would be a better solution (about performances). In case you'd need it, you could use the `HAVING` clause (you can't perform a `WHERE number >= 10`):

```
SELECT
    item,
    COUNT(*) as number
FROM shop
GROUP BY item
HAVING number >= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two options to filter the data so only the rows with more then 10 will appear.

1. At the SQL query

__

```
SELECT item, COUNT(*) as number FROM shop GROUP BY item HAVING number > 9
```

This will cause you to recieve only the requested rows from the database

2. **Filter with PHP** - every time you want to print the menu or testing it out, just can the value of '**number**' in the array reutrned from the query. You can also allocate new array and insert all the values that contains '**number**' that bigger then 10.

Comment: Indeed, I am looking for option 2 but I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

I noticed php is tagged. For the sake of options, here's how I'd go about separating the unneeded data in php if you were to get it from the database as-is:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $num = (int) $item['number']; // force of habit
    if ($num >= 10) {
        // display it
    }
}
```

I'd probably separate the data at the database step, but this works if it's the route you want to take.